# Uploaded images cut off

Tags: wordpress, image

I have a problem with new images. When I'm uploading a new image it looks like this: [image]

Any suggestions how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem. Every time I added an image into a page, part would be cropped off.  I tried playing with the settings > media etc, turned off the Smush plugin, changed the image size and dimensions in photoshop. But part of the image still kept getting trimmed off when uploading. Finally, I uploaded the image directly into Media, where it looked fine.  Tried placing it in the page - cut off again.  Copied and pasted the image code into the page and it shows up fine.  I haven't nailed down the issue, but at least this is a workaround if it is only one or two problematic images.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `settings > media` and you will see your image settings. What is happening is that the image you are uploading is too large and thus it gets cropped. Uncheck `Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions (normally thumbnails are proportional)`, and your images will get scaled rather than cropped.

If this is still no good to you, then you will have to jump into the code that is displaying the images.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `Settings -> Media`, you should set `width` or `height` to `0`.  In this way, that dimension will be scaled and nothing is cut off.
If you set `width` to `0`, vertical (height > width) images will be reduced, and horizontal images will be enlarged a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that img is cut at the top or/and at the bottom, you probably have a hard crop in your template.
[This might help you](https://github.com/tomaszsita/wp-manual-image-crop)

Or, try a work around:

Add a high-quality, max-height image, then you can and scale it up with `transform: scale(1.5);` in css.

Hope that helps.